# How to separate a collection inside a column in spark-dataframe and pass the values to other column?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose this is a dataframe :

```
val data = Seq(
  Row("Ramesh",List("English","German"),Map("hair"->"black","eye"->"brown")),
  Row("Vijay",List("Spark","French",null),Map("hair"->"brown","eye"->null)),
  Row("Yann",List("Mandrin",""),Map("hair"->"red","eye"->"")),
  Row("Ram",null,null),
  Row("Jefferson",List(),Map())
)

val schema = new StructType()
  .add("name",StringType)
  .add("languages", ArrayType(StringType))
  .add("properties", MapType(StringType,StringType))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)
```

OUTPUT :

```
+----------+--------------+
|name      |languages     |
+----------+--------------+
```

I want all the output with names with atomic values. Null should also be covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `explode_outer` from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`. This flattens the collection in the dataframe. And outer command considers the null value.

```
df.select($"name",explode_outer($"languages"))
  .show(false)
```

Comment: Okay. Thank You.